# What is so special about 1d and 2d?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, dimension-theory-analysis

**Preface:** To be specific, the following is written about Euclidian space. However, I'm interested in what's going on in other spaces as well.

I've been told several times that $1d$ and $2d$ spaces are somewhat special, i.e. some mathematical properties tend to have abnormalities in these dimensions. These are some I know:

- (For $2d$) Complex analysis, which is a distinct topic in mathematics by itself, exists purely in $2d$;
- (From partial differential equation theory) The solution of the homogeneous wave equation differs depending on the dimension. For $3d$ the solution is the Kirchhoff formula where there is an integral over a sphere which causes a sharp front. For $2d$ the solution is the Poisson formula where the integral is over a disk which causes a non-sharp front. For $1d$ the solution is the D'Alembert formula where the integral is over a line which again causes a non-sharp front.
- (Again from partial differential equation theory) The fundamental solution of the Laplace operator is  $\frac{1}{2\pi}ln|x|$ for $n=2$ and $-\frac{1}{(n-2)s_n|x|^{n-2}}$ for $n\geq3$. Unfortunately, I don't know the solution for $n=1$.

**The questions:**

- What causes these dimensions to be so special? Is there a hidden meaning?
- (For the sake of interest) If you know, please suggest some other examples of such abnormalities, if any exist.

Comment: " Complex analysis, which is a distinct topic in mathematics by itself, exists purely in 2d" [Not really.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Several_complex_variables) That said, there is some weak truth to the claim in that multivariable complex analysis is much harder than single-variable complex analysis, which is very unlike the real situation. Meanwhile, your second example just observes that "The solution of the homogeneous wave equation differs depending on the dimension," but doesn't pick out anything *specifically* interesting about $1$ or $2$.

Comment: The [Generalized Poincare conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Poincar%C3%A9_conjecture) and related results show [Homotopy spheres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_sphere) in dimension 5 or greater are exotic spheres, in dimension 3 or less are spheres themselves.  The case of dimension 4 is still open.

Comment: You can have a look to [Results true in a dimension and false for higher dimensions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/180846/results-true-in-a-dimension-and-false-for-higher-dimensions) for similar questions though not specifically for dimensions one and two.

Comment: @NoahSchweber about complex analysis: didn't know that. About pde: well, don't you think it is a bit strange? the fundamental solution of the Laplace operator can be in fact described in one formula and the properties are very similar, but not in 2d (and maybe 1d, I don't know).

Comment: @OlegYablokov Not really. Or rather, from the limited data presented I have no idea $(i)$ how significant that is or $(ii)$ which is the "usual" situation (what's the case with dimension $15$? maybe dimension $3$ is exciting and $1, 2$ are boringly normal!).